# Populating textboxes in gridview with values from datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, sqldataadapter

I have a gridview displaying students, each row has a textbox where their mark can be entered. I am trying to pull the current 'Mark' value from the database table and put it into the textbox for that specific student, however the last value in the datatable is repeated for every student.

How can i get the datatable values to populate each row of the gridview seperately?

```
        TextBox marks = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("MarkTextBox");

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {

            int Mark = (int)dr["Mark"];
            marks.Text = Mark.ToString();

        }

    }
```

Comment: and what issue are you facing ?

Comment: the same value from the datarow is being repeated in each gridview row instead of the unique grades returned from the query

Comment: what event is this? RowDataBound?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the RowDataBound event, your code runs for *each* row.

So for the first *gridview* row, you're looping the entire table and setting the textbox value to the current *table* row. meaning, the last value in the table will always be the value *for each gridview row*.

So in the RowDataBound event you need to

- get the current row count (say it's 3);
- get the value from the table in row 3 and set the textbox;

on the next RowDataBound (they all run at one time), your code will get row 4, and you'll set the textbox to the value in the 4th row of the table.

Comment: Yes it is a RowDataBound event. I understand what your point is but i still can't get the logic to populate each row correctly. I have tried this;

for (int i = 0; i < gradeAlways.Rows.Count; i++){
                
TextBox marks = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("MarkTextBox");
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(dt);

           foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            int Mark = (int)dr["Mark"];
                            marks.Text = Mark.ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, thanks for your help @wazz

TextBox marks = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("MarkTextBox");

```
        for (int i = 0; i < gradeAlways.Rows.Count +1; i++)
        {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                    var Mark = dt.Rows[i]["Mark"];
                        marks.Text = Mark.ToString();


            }
```

I had to put gradeAlways.Rows.Count **+1**